# Is there any way I can re-use an XML pattern constraint expression in SQL Server TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, xml

Is there any simple way to transfer a Regular Expression from an [XML Schema pattern constraint](https://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html) to SQL Server?

I have to check if a string field meets the condition.

`[axyto0-9\s]{0,2}[\s0-9]{0,10}`

- Start of string
- A single character present in the list below between 
  zero and 2 times, as many times as possible

  - A single character from the list “axyto” (case sensitive)
  - A character in the range between “0” and “9”
  - A “whitespace character”
- Match a single character present in the list below between zero and 10 times, as many times as possible

  - A “whitespace character”
  - A character in the range between “0” and “9”
- End of string

Comment: `[axyto0-9\s]｛0，2｝[\s0-9]{0,10}` is not XML. That's Regex. A ***completely*** different thing.

Comment: @Larnu XML Schema does define [its own limited Regular Expression flavour](https://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html) that can be used in a `pattern` constraint

Comment: That doesn't change that what the OP has provided isn't XML though, @MartinSmith . Whether or not a XML supports Regex, that string alone is not valid XML.

Comment: to be fair to them they never said it was XML. They just used the term "XML pattern". In this case the fact the regex is using that flavour is very relevant as SQL Server has built in support for XML schema validation

Comment: As this question is closed but I found the possibilities interesting I asked a self answered question on the DBA site inspired by it. https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/266438/3690